# Slideshow angular not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Have found an example of how to make a slideshow with Angular, it is almost done. But the slide-effect to the left does not work like in this example. http://plnkr.co/edit/BxWNlYVJUCNL7C1K65aU?p=preview

Anyone an idea what I have done wrong.

```js
var pictures = angular.module("myApp", [])
 .controller("SlideShowController", function($scope,  $timeout) {
 var slideInSlideshow = 4;
 var slideTimeInterval = 4000;

 $scope.slider = 1;
  var slideTimer =
  $timeout(function interval() {
   
  $scope.slider = ($scope.slider % slideInSlideshow) + 1;


  slideTimer = $timeout(interval, slideTimeInterval);
 }, slideTimeInterval);
   
 var image = {
  one: "image/image01.jpg", 
  two: "image/image02.jpg", 
  three: "image/image03.jpg", 
  four: "image/image04.jpg"
 };
 
  $scope.image = image;
 });
```

```css
.slideshow {
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.slider {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: .3em;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.slideshow .slider-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}

.slide-image {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.animate-enter,.animate-leave {
 -webkit-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 -moz-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 -ms-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 -o-transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
 transition:1000ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) all;
}

.animate-enter {
 margin-left: 100%;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
 margin-left:0;
}

.animate-leave {
 margin-left:0;
}

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
 margin-left:-100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="SlideShowController" class="slideshow"  ng-switch="slider" ng-animate="'animate'">
  <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="1">
   <img ng-src="{{image.one}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-m3-picture" />
  </div>

  <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="2">
   <img ng-src="{{image.two}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-mx6-picture"/>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="3">
   <img ng-src="{{image.three}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-m3s-picture"/> 
  </div>

  <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="4">
   <img ng-src="{{image.four}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-m3e-picture"/>
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong.  ngAnimate was deprecated in Angular 1.2, so you'll need to make changes to your code. https://johnpapa.net/preparing-for-animations-in-angular-1-2-0/

If you switch to an earlier version (1.1.5 below, as in the Plnker) you'll see your code worked fine.

```js
var pictures = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("SlideShowController", function($scope, $timeout) {
    var slideInSlideshow = 4;
    var slideTimeInterval = 1000;

    $scope.slider = 1;
    var slideTimer =
      $timeout(function interval() {

        $scope.slider = ($scope.slider % slideInSlideshow) + 1;


        slideTimer = $timeout(interval, slideTimeInterval);
      }, slideTimeInterval);

    var image = {
      one: "image/image01.jpg",
      two: "image/image02.jpg",
      three: "image/image03.jpg",
      four: "image/image04.jpg"
    };

    $scope.image = image;
  });
```

```css
#mainbody {
 width:50%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.slideshow {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slider {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: .3em;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.slideshow .slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.slide-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.animate-enter,
.animate-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) all;
  -moz-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) all;
  -ms-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) all;
  -o-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) all;
  transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) all;
}
.animate-enter {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.animate-leave {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

```html
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SlideShowController" class="slideshow" ng-switch="slider" ng-animate="'animate'">
    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="1">
      <img ng-src="{{image.one}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-m3-picture" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="2">
      <img ng-src="{{image.two}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-mx6-picture" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="3">
      <img ng-src="{{image.three}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-m3s-picture" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="4">
      <img ng-src="{{image.four}}" class="slide-image" alt="meizu-m3e-picture" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```